# Which one is more general, attribute based encryption or inner product predicate encryption?

Tags: public-key, terminology, abe, functional-encryption, predicate-encryption

1. If we have a scheme for inner product predicate encryption (IPPE), then can we claim that we already have designed an attribute based encryption (ABE) scheme; So we do not need to design an ABE again. I mean, is IPPE more general than ABE?
2. What about predicate encryption (PE)? I think PE is more general than ABE, Right?